# Is there any way to prevent modelines getting reapplied when files are saved / written?

Tags: folding, modeline

For some Markdown documents, I like them to open with some sections initially folded (I use the plugin [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/masukomi/vim-markdown-folding)). I've tried setting a modeline that looks like this:

```
<!-- vi: set foldmethod=indent foldlevel=1: -->
```

This works, but unfortunately, every time I save the buffer, even with it still open, the folding is reset back to `foldlevel` 1. I'd really like it if the modeline only took effect when the file is first opened.

Is this possible?

Comment: does this happen with `vim --clean`? I wonder if there is some autocommand or something triggering this; nothing in the modeline help indicates this is default behavior

Comment: Does it prevent Vim from re-reading the modeline if you use `:noautocmd w` to save?

Comment: Yes, @D.BenKnoble is right. It shouldn't be so. Try `:au BufWrite` to see if it's set up by some plugin or such.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the helpful comments. I didn't realise that this was not default behaviour. But with some binary searching in disabling plugins, I was able to find out that this was due to my use of the [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/masukomi/vim-markdown-folding) plugin (which in retrospect seems obvious, sorry). Its `foldexpr` overrides the one I was using and causes this issue. I may discontinue my use of the plugin or see if there is a way to use it which can be disabled for specific files.